# Distinguishability and energy of a system

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm studying distinguishability in quantum mechanics but I'm confused with the calculation of energies.

Suppose we are given a hamiltonian for 1 particle with two possible sites
$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & t \\
    t & 0  
\end{bmatrix}$$

With this hamiltonian we have of course two eigenstates $\psi_S$ ans $\psi_A$. Assume this particle now has also spin 1/2. Assume this particle is under the same influence of the hamiltonian introduced above. Then the 4x4 bew hailtonian for 1 particle is

$$ H' = \begin{bmatrix}    1 & 0 \\0 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}    0 & t \\t & 0  \end{bmatrix} $$

Where the first part of the tensor product corresponds to the spin space and the second to the site space (Could someone tell me if this is correct?).

Now assume instead of one particle, now we have two DISTINGUISHABLE particles. This is where I get confused. Since we have two quantum systems not interacting between them, then the eigenstates for the two particle system may be given by tensor products of the 1 particle states. In other words, since we had 4 eigenstates for the one particle system, in the two distinguishable particle system we have 16 eigenstates, composed of all possible combinations. Also is this is the case, the hamiltonian for the 2 particle (distinguishable) system is given by $H' \otimes H'$ (I'm not sure this is correct, although I would assume since both systems dont interact then the hamiltonian acts independantly on each particle). If this is the case then the eigenvalues will be of order $t^2$. For example consider $\psi_{S \uparrow} \otimes \psi_{S\uparrow}$

Yet I can think of an argument so that they are only of order $t$. If we have two particles that don't interact with each other, then the total energy will be just the sum of the energy of both systems. Thus for $\psi_{S \uparrow} \otimes \psi_{S\uparrow}$ the energy will be $2t$. I'm very confused about this and any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hamiltonian of composite system is not a tensor product, but a sum

$$
H_{comp} = H'_1 + H'_2
$$

where $H_1'$ acts on the part of state vector that describes the first system, and $H_2'$ acts on the part that describes the second one.

This is consistent with your argument that total energy of noninteracting two systems should be sum of their energies.

The tensor product is present in the composite Hamiltonian in the sense that

$$
H_1' = H' \otimes 1_2 
$$

$$
H_2' = 1_1 \otimes H'
$$

where $1_1$ is unit matrix acting on the coordinates of the first system, and $1_2$ is unit matrix acting on the coordinates of the second system.